# Understanding the basics of copy on write

Tags: c++, proxy, copy

With regard to this line:

The `s[9]` that goes through `void setChar(size_t index, char c)`, but what is `*this` (inside the if, in the line: ``)?

Is it `s1` or `nullptr`? Then what is `_str` (in the same line: `*this = _str;`), is it `s1`?

```
class MyString {
    size_t _size = 0;
    char* _str = nullptr;
    int* _pRefCount = nullptr;


        }
        operator char() const {
            return ((const MyString&)_s)[_index];
        }
    }; 

    void detach() {

        if(_pRefCount && --*_pRefCount == 0) {
            delete []_str;
            delete _pRefCount;
        }
    }

    void attach(const MyString& str) {
        _size = str._size;
        _str = str._str;
        _pRefCount = str._pRefCount;
        ++*_pRefCount;
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, examining the values of all variables and objects, what observations did you make concerning the question that you asked? You do know how to use a debugger to answer these kind of simple questions all by yourself, right? Because, as everyone knows, knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Then how is  "_str"  there?

Comment: It's there because it's there. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

As always `*this` is the object the function is executed for. If you are inside `s1[4]` the `*this` would be `s1`.

Using `*this = _str;` is just an involved way of calling one of the `operator=` overloads for `MyString`. It has the effect of "unsharing" by assigning a new copy of `_str` to itself.

Also, it has been known for quite some time that reference counted strings is not an optimization. For example in the output of `s1[0]` the code will create an unnecessary `CharProxy` just in case someone would assign a value to it. You also get a separate memory allocation for the refcount of each string you create, even if you never intend to share it

Comment: But s1 is an Object while _str is a member, why assignment works? Is it an assignment of the same object to itself: because _str is also "Hello"?

Comment: It's a (C-style) string whether it is a member or not, so it creates a new `MyString` and assigns it to itself. That way the string is not shared anymore. Some parts of the code are a bit too "clever". If I were you I wouldn't waste too much time trying to understand it. It's not very useful.